# where are mozilla margins stored in registry?

Tags: firefox

I want to export registry keys for pagesetup in firefox after edit it in interface like IE to import it to many comuters

in IE the registry key exist in the fllowing path

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup

but in firefox I did'nt it

help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page setup setting for firefox browser don't stored in registry but in file on your computer in 

C:\Documents and Settings\PC_NAME\Application Data\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\79kt0c75.default